# Docker won't run a container after creating a symbolic link

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I have access to a 10Gb virtual machine, which was already at 99% disk usage. In order to start a new container I moved my docker directory (previously at `/var/snap/docker`) to another disk where I have as much space as I need, and created a symbolic link at `/var/snap` called `docker`.

Now when I try to run a container it prints out:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/833f49d424b2b1089aee6989bda609fa85d3a72540142c464e00e1fa4eec0a3b/merged is not an absolute path or is a symlink: unknown
Error: failed to start containers: ycsb
```

I don't know what I did wrong, or if this isn't supposed to work at all.

Comment: "Error ... or is a symlink" -- seems pretty clear to me that symlinks are not allowed

Answer (score 1):

This used to work (to at least v19.03.1), but now does not.

However, you can explicitly change the Docker rootdir that the daemon uses, which is more secure.

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452368/change-docker-root-dir-on-red-hat-linux:

Edit (or create) the /etc/docker/daemon.json file so that it reads

```
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/your-volume/var/snap/docker",
   ...other possible entries...
}
```

Restart the daemon with

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

And try your run.